# Is alav ha-shalom (A"H) used often, or do most use zikhrono livrakha (Z"L) when referring to the deceased?

Tags: death, mourning-aveilus, funeral-burial-levaya

I understand that A"H is translates to "may he/she rest in peace," which is indeed closer to what non-Jews say in gentile societies. However, I also understand Z"L is also an honorific for the dead, which translates to "may his/her memory be a blessing" or "of blessed memory." Which is more common among Jews? Which is more proper, and for what occasions?

Comment: On most Jewish sites I've run across, Z"L is the one used.  Somebody here knows why and lots more, I'm sure.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) AviG. Hope to see you around!

Comment: I think both are used. For example, it's always _Moshe Rabbeinu a''h_ but _Ari z''l_. I'd say _zichrono livracha_ is more common though.

Comment: So Ezra, are you saying that only prophets and biblical figures get A"H?

Comment: @ezra that's because Moshe and not the Ari was referred to in Tanakh as עבד השם

Comment: @AviG Yes; see DoubleAA's comment above.

Comment: Why is alav hashalom more of an issue than shalom aleichem?

Answer (score 3):

Great rabbis and other figures -- other than Moses, see below -- tend to get *zichrono livracha* (or *zecher tzadik livracha*). *Alav hashalom* is something you'll hear colloquially about a parent or something who wasn't necessarily a great scholar. (Though it's still acceptable to reverse those.)
And then there's Moses, for whom the phrase *alav hashalom* was coined!

*Alav haShalom* actually arrived at Hebrew via the Arabic! Islam refers to their central prophet as "peace [and blessings] be upon him", so when Maimonides (who lived in Muslim lands almost all his life) wrote in Judeo-Arabic, he wrote "Moses our Teacher -- peace be upon him!" Those works were later translated into Hebrew, and the phrase *alav hashalom* stuck.

Comment: Actually ע"ה originally meant עבד השם and was used for biblical greats only. Later with the influence of Islam people reinterpreted the acronym to mean Peace Be Upon Him, but that's not really a Jewish thing

Comment: You also quite often hear Avraham Avinu alav hashalom, especially in the context of brit milah

Comment: @joel another instance of אברהם אבינו עבד השם being corrupted

Comment: I'm seeing on a lot of websites from synagogues, religious websites, etc. that Z"L is used way more than A"H